# Error: Operacion de archivo no permitida. Acceso a la ruta denegado C# SILVERLIGHT

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que utiliza Silverlight, en donde quiero mostrar archivos PDFS de una ruta de un servidor, pero al momento de ir debugeando mi codigo me encuentro con la siguiente excepcion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en donde genero el flujo en el siguiente codigo:

```html
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlElement myFrame = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.GetElementById("_sl_historyFrame");
            if (myFrame != null)
            {
                DirectoryInfo folderPath = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.216\UploadFileMobilePDF\" + transfer.IdTransfer);
                foreach (var file in folderPath.EnumerateFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("width", "1024");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("height", "768");
                    Uri uri = new Uri(folderPath + file.FullName);
                    string path = uri.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
                    myFrame.SetAttribute("src", path);
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("left", "0");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("top", "50");
                    myFrame.SetStyleAttribute("visibility", "visible");
                }
            }
```

El error me marca al instanciar la clase DirectoryInfo folderPath = new DirectoryInfo()

No se si silverlight no puede tener permisos a direcciones de servidores

Comment: Te recomiendo que dejes de usar Silverlight, ya que es una libreria obsoleta.

Comment: El problema es que el proyecto en el que trabajo usa Silverlight ya desde hace tiempo, y no encuentro la forma de abrir archivos PDF de un servidor

Comment: Intenta poner la ruta local del servidor en lugar de la que tienes. Por otro lado, es posible que aun asi tengas un problema de permisos y tengas que impersora algun usuario que tenga permiso de acceso a dicha ruta.